Firefox Download Filename Format
I am using Firefox as my daily browser. Is there an extension or setting I can set so that whenever I download any file from the Internet it prepends to the file name "firefox_{date}{time}" + "{original_filename}" format? I tried to use Grease Monkey but couldn't get it to work. Kudos if it shows up when it prompts me where to save the file.
